# Pagination stopped working after assigning custom page template to new page (different slug)

Tags: pagination, page-template

I am having a problem with pagination on one of my CPT after assigning the custom page template to a different page with a different slug. It all worked perfectly on the test page I developed it with. Only after the new assignment did I run into this issue for subsequent pages (2,3,etc.). Page 1 still works fine. I did resave the Permalinks in WP after the assignment of the custom page template and cleared and rebuild all caches (WP Rocket, WP Engine, Cloudflare).

I also tried modifying the CPT by removing 'hierarchical' => true and 'capability_type' => 'page' but that did seem to have any effect either.

I am sure I am missing clearing something somewhere as it was working perfectly before the template reassignment.

You can see the working one here (click on '2' below the pictures): https://totalk9focus.com/test-page/
You can see the non-working one here (click on '2' below the pictures): https://totalk9focus.com/client-pictures/

I hope someone can help me sort this out.

Attached code sections: **Definition of the CPT in functions.php** | **Query for the pages** | **Footer section with pagination links**

````
    register_post_type( 'pictures',
        array( 
                'labels'            => array(
                                        'name'          => __( 'Pictures' ),
                                        'singular_name' => __( 'Picture' )          
                                    ),
                '_builtin'          => false,
                'public'            => true, 
                'show_ui'           => true,
                'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
                'menu_position'       => 6,
                'hierarchical'      => true,
                'capability_type'   => 'page',
                'menu_icon'           => ( version_compare( $GLOBALS['wp_version'], '3.8', '>=' ) ) ? 'dashicons-format-image' : '',
                'rewrite'           => array(
                    'slug'       => 'client-pictures',
                    'with_front' => FALSE,
                ),
                'supports' => array(
                        'title',
                        'editor',
                        'thumbnail',
                        'excerpt',
                        'custom-fields',
                        'post-formats'
                        )
                    ) 
                );
}
add_action('init', 'my_post_type_client_pictures'); ```

**Query for the pages**

``` get_header(); 

/* Get Pictures */
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'pictures',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'publish_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'paged' => $paged,
);
$arr_posts = new WP_Query( $args ); ```

**Footer section with pagination links**

```                         $total_pages = $arr_posts->max_num_pages;

                        if ($total_pages > 1){

                            $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

                            echo paginate_links(array(
                                'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
                                'format' => 'page/%#%/',
                                'current' => $current_page,
                                'total' => $total_pages,
                                'prev_text'    => __('« prev'),
                                'next_text'    => __('next »'),
                            ));
                        } ```
````